# Usando strong attributes com rails 4 e relacionamento has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relacionamento

Tenho um relacionamento `has_one` parecido com o seu onde uma `:person` possui um `:address`.

Acontece que o relacionamento é gerado mas a rua que coloco no `input :street` (atributo de address) não é salvo. Já coloquei conforme seu modelo acima e retorna erro *ADDRESS IS NOT DEFINED*.

Se puder me dar uma ajuda, ficarei grata.

o laboratório está no github: https://github.com/vanessasoutoc/labHasOne

```
address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
end

person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

people_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def address
        @address
    end

    def addresses_atributes=(attributes)

    end

    # GET /people
    # GET /people.json
    def index
        @people = Person.all
    end

    # GET /people/1
    # GET /people/1.json
    def show
    end

    # GET /people/new
    def new
        @person = Person.new
        @person.build_address
    end

    # GET /people/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /people
    # POST /people.json
    def create
        @person = Person.new(person_params)
        @person.build_address
        respond_to do |format|
            if @person.save
                format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @person }
            else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /people/1
    # PATCH/PUT /people/1.json
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @person.update(person_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @person }
            else
                format.html { render :edit }
                format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # DELETE /people/1
    # DELETE /people/1.json
    def destroy
        @person.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to people_url, notice: 'Person was successfully destroyed.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_person
        @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    private
    def person_params
        params.require(:person).permit(:name, :cpf, addresses_atributes: [:street, :zip_code])
    end

end

#/people/_form.html.erb
<##%= form_for(@person) do |person_form| %>




  <div class="field">
    <%#= person_form.label :name %><br>
    <%#= person_form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%#= person_form.label :cpf %><br>
    <%#= person_form.text_field :cpf %>
  </div>
  <%#= person_form.fields_for :address do |address_form| %>
  <div class="field">
      <%#= address_form.label :street %>
      <%#= address_form.text_field :street %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%#= address_form.label :zip_code %>
      <%#= address_form.text_field :zip_code %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%#= person_form.submit %>
  </div>
<#% end %>
```

Comment: Pode colocar a classe que define address? Além disso, tente dar mais detalhes. Fica muito difícil encontrar o problema, sendo que você só passou o projeto GitHub pra isso...

Comment: Bem vinda o SOpt, faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor como funciona a nossa comunidade. Explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Acontece o seguinte tenho dois models, person e address. Quando eu crio uma pessoa ele tem que gerar o ralacionamento entre person e address, e ele gera o relacionamento... entretando o endereço (:street) e demais informações que eu insiro atraves do fields_for não estão sendo salvos no banco de dados...

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Obrigada por ajudarem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem dois problemas no seu código. O primeiro é o nome do parâmetro aninhado do modelo `address` lá no `person_params`.

**people_controller.rb**

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :cpf, address_attributes: [:street, :zip_code])
end
```

E o outro problema está no método `create`, você deve retirar a linha `@person.build_address`, pois ele não é necessária quando você já está criando um registro com os dados submetidos pelo usuário, use o `build_address` apenas no método `new`.

---

Lembre-se que você deve olhar também o log da sua app para descobrir esse tipo de problema, veja o log quando eu submeto o form para criar uma pessoa:

```
tarted POST "/people" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-20 11:02:06 -0200
Processing by PeopleController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"rcEOWTBmMgcq3tOrNUiDForZnlB6tI4MGtg9mWurSDQ=",
    "person"=>{
      "name"=>"Person",
      "cpf"=>"0000000000",
      "address_attributes" => { "street"=>"Street name"}
    },
    "commit"=>"Create Person"
   }
```

Ai estava a resposta para o problema do nome errado no `person_params`.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo. Já testei aqui e funcionou..
Tava quase desistindo. Erros de bobeirinha.. 

Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou! Depois dê uma lida aqui para ajudar o stackoverflow http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers =)

Comment: Pesoal nem vota quando recebe ajuda, toma meu voto @Peoplee